# Foliations and groupoids in algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, groupoids, foliations

I am currently studying the theory of foliations and groupoids from a differentiable viewpoint, in particular Haefliger spaces. [See [Segal, *Classifying spaces related to foliations*](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0040938378900046), and [Moerdijk, *Classifying toposes and foliations*](http://www.numdam.org/article/AIF_1991__41_1_189_0.pdf).]

I read that there are related notions of groupoids and foliations in algebraic geometry, particulary in the context of schemes. Is there a basic reference where to study this theory? Assume as background a basic course on schemes and several courses in "classical" algebraic geometry.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you try "Birational geometry of foliations " ? This is mainly about surfaces but it might be a start.